# Не понимаю, почему такая ошибка

Tags: django, django-orm

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index_url'),
    path('<slug:brand>/', views.brand_filter, name='brand_url')


def brand_filter(request, brand):
    brand_product_list = Product.objects.filter(brand=brand)
    current_brand = Brand.objects.get(name=brand)
    return render(request, 'branded.html', {'brand_product_list': brand_product_list, 'current_brand': current_brand})
```

ПРиобращении на адрес второго пути из списка выдается ошибка: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'Fischer'.

Comment: приведите полный трейсбэк ошибки

Comment: Проверьте, нет ли еще одного паттерна с тем же именем в других файлах, который резолвится раньше ожидаемого?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не понимаю, в чем ошибка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1159330/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%8e-%d0%b2-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0)

Comment: думаю што фишер это brand и проблема связана со slug скорее всего. Где-то ожидается id а вы передаете slug. Из данного кода и полного трейсбека ошибки не понять